# Trying to upload multiple resized images in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload multiple images to a folder and save an *encrypted image name* in db. However, the code I have written, resizes the image, but saves *original image name* in database.

Example: if the encrypted original file is abc.jpg, the resized one is xyz.jpg. The db saves abc.jpg.

```
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];

        //new code
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/advert_images';
        $target_path = './uploads/advert_images/thumbs';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000000'; //limit 1 mb
        $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
        $config['overwrite'] = false;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_width'] = '5000';// image max width
        $config['max_height'] = '5000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $error = array('upload_error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error',  $error['upload_error']);
            echo $files['userfile']['name'][$i].' '.$error['upload_error']; exit;

        } // resize code
        $path=$data['upload_data']['full_path'];
        $q['name']=$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $configi['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configi['source_image']   = $path;
        $configi['new_image']   = $target_path;
        $configi['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $configi['width']  = 300; // new size
        $configi['height'] = 300;
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->image_lib->initialize($configi);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        unlink($path);

        $insert[$i]['picture_file_name']=$this->upload->data('file_name');;

        $insert[$i]['add_id']=$last_insert_id;
    }

    $response=$this->db->insert_batch('product_pictures',$insert);
```

Comment: So you want to store the resized image name in the db? Why don't you have the resized image name to be like `abc-resized.jpg` or `resized/abc.jpg` instead of `xyz.jpg` and get the resized image name from the original image name stored in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your [File Upload Preferences](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload#preferences) you also need, in addition to `encrypt_name()`, set `file_name()` as well:

> If set CodeIgniter will rename the uploaded file to this name. The
> extension provided in the file name must also be an allowed file type.
> If no extension is provided in the original file_name will be used.

Comment: This worked fine, also how to delete teh file in the location $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/advert_images'; anfter the resizing is done, i dont want to keep the files. I have put as "unlink($path);" but the files are still there

Comment: @dinesh *How to delete the file*: I'd suggest that you ask a new question, to treat this issue separately.

Comment: i have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62774239/how-to-delete-files-after-uploading-in-php-codeigniter