# how to delete files after uploading in php codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-upload

I am uploading multiple images using the following code:

```
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];

        //new code
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/advert_images';
        $target_path = './uploads/advert_images/thumbs';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000000'; //limit 1 mb
        $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
        $config['overwrite'] = false;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_width'] = '5000';// image max width
        $config['max_height'] = '5000';


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $error = array('upload_error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error',  $error['upload_error']);
            echo $files['userfile']['name'][$i].' '.$error['upload_error']; exit;

        } // resize code
        $path=$data['upload_data']['full_path'];
        $file_name_new=$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $q['name']=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $configi['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configi['source_image']   = $path;
        $configi['new_image']   = $target_path;
        $configi['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $configi['width']  = 300; // new size
        $configi['height'] = 300;
        $configi['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->image_lib->initialize($configi);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        unlink($path);

        $insert[$i]['picture_file_name']=$file_name_new;

        $insert[$i]['add_id']=$last_insert_id;
    }

    $response=$this->db->insert_batch('product_pictures',$insert);

    if ($response) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Advert added successfully');
        redirect('Site/create_adverts');
    }


}
```

What i need to do is to delete the original files uploaded to the advert_images folder, but keep only the ones inside thumbs folder.I tried to delete using unlink, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463678/2275490, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Are you getting any error when using `unlink`?

Comment: No nothing happens, i changes the permissions too, still the same files remain as it is.

Comment: @Vickel - Don't you mean the other way around? It expects the path to be a valid file (file path) and not a directory (directory path).